# How to hide a text box that was created by angularjs ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I have three labels and textboxes that are being created by an ng-repeat.

```
            <ul class="modusScriptingHiddenList">
            <li ng-repeat="fld in allFields">
                <label class="control-label">{{fld.Name}}</label>

                <div ng-if="fld.IsSelect == true">
                    <select name="{{fld.Name}}">
                        <option ng-repeat="params in fld.Results" value="{{ params.Key }}" name="{{params.Value}}">{{ params.Value }}</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div ng-if="fld.IsSelect == false">
                        <input type="text" name="{{fld.Name}}" />
                </div>

            </li>
            </ul>
```

I want to hide the label and the textbox for any field named 'Field1'. How do you accomplish this using angularjs?

Comment: What is the criteria for showing and hiding? You are almost certainly going to use an `ng-if` directive.

Comment: When fld.Name = Item1, I want to hide the label and it's textbox. I tried using ng-if="{fld.Name == "Item1"}" on the label but it removes all labels.

Comment: You can add an `ng-if="field.Name !== 'Item1'"` to any elements that should not be rendered if `field.Name` is "Item1"

Answer (score 1):

```
// You could use ng-show and test for a boolean value
<div ng-show="myValue"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide the label and the textbox for any field named 'Item1', this is how you would do it. You would use `ng-if="fld.Name !== 'Item1'`

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('MyController', function($scope) {
  var results = [
     {Key: '1', Value: '1'}, 
     {Key: '2', Value: '2'}, 
     {Key: '2', Value: '2'}
  ];  
  
  $scope.allFields = [{
    Name: 'Item3',
    IsSelect: true,
    Results: results
  }, {
    Name: 'Item2',
    IsSelect: false,
    Results: results
  }, {
    Name: 'Item1',
    IsSelect: true,
    Results: results
  }];

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MyController">
  <ul class="modusScriptingHiddenList">
    <li ng-repeat="fld in allFields">
      <label ng-if="fld.Name !=='Item1'" class="control-label">{{fld.Name}}</label>

      <div ng-if="fld.IsSelect == true">
        <select name="{{fld.Name}}">
          <option ng-repeat="params in fld.Results" value="{{ params.Key }}" name="{{params.Value}}">{{ params.Value }}</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div ng-if="fld.Name !== 'Item1'">
        <input type="text" name="{{fld.Name}}" />
      </div>

    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Since the item that I am trying to hide is the last piece, I was able to accomplish what I needed by applying the following line to both the label and the text box.

```
            ng-if="!$last"
```

Comment: This may have been the answer to the question in your mind, but not to the question you asked.